# How do I use an animated SVG for navbar link hover, and position it properly?

Tags: html, css, animation, svg

I’m building my portfolio and it has a theme as if it's been drawn on paper.

When you hover over a link on my navbar, the SVG animates from underneath, it's an arrow that points to the link and it looks like it's been drawn with a sharpie. I would also like to animation to reverse on mouse out, instead of just disappearing.

The animation works awesomely on hover (by itself), exactly as I want, however I cannot figure out how to make it appear on a navbar link hover instead. Also, I'm unsure how to position it. Currently I have the SVG placed after my `<a>` tags.

Here's the code:

```css
div {
  border: 1px black solid;
  width: 120px;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}

#arrowSVG:hover path {
  animation: nav_arrow 800ms linear 1 normal forwards;
}

@keyframes nav_arrow {
  0%,
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 228.816432;
  }
  60% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p> Hover me!
    </>
    <svg id="arrowSVG" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 128 128" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision" text-rendering="geometricPrecision">
      <path id="eZuEQXWsHpA2" d="M81.33906,95.61239c-2.04913-2.92733-15.33188-23.55344-18.27718-23.9216-2.1176-.2647-6.39806,6.74064-9.13859,
                      5.64442-1.72253-.68901-.23957-19.37568,1.07513-20.42744.35406-.28324,17.10175,10.91579,16.93327,12.09519-.24773,1.73411-10.42713,
                      4.21185-12.09519,4.56929-2.16723.46441-8.43321,2.60391-6.45077,1.61269c3.20375-1.60188,6.85172-2.25839,9.67615-4.56929.39226-.32094,
                      1.55594-1.2354,1.07513-1.07513-.88133.29378-11.28885,4.35372-11.28885,4.30051c0-2.22645,10.47757-5.91321,12.36397-5.91321c1.02153,
                      0-1.18114-1.93573-2.15025-1.61269-2.93453.97818-11.8009,6.50634-9.94494,4.03173c2.11065-2.81419,10.07996-2.15151,11.02006-4.03173.26335-.5267-10.04599,
                      1.11958-10.4825.53757-2.04355-2.72474,8.60103-2.59902,8.60103-3.76295c0-1.26705-8.19827,1.07445-8.86981,0-.76572-1.22515,1.75021-2.86552,
                      2.15026-3.49417.30422-.47805.18968-1.16541.53756-1.61269c1.16554-1.49856,2.42055,6.98982,3.76296,8.33224c4.42514,4.42514,10.96031-4.00183,9.40736,3.76295" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-dashoffset="228.816432" stroke-dasharray="228.816432" />
</div>
```

Comment: in order to make the animation reverse on mouse out you can try using transition instead of animation. The other part of your question is not very clear to me

Comment: Please could you add in a snippet of what you have tried with the navbar and which doesn't work as you wish - the snippet you have provided works, apart from the sudden disappearance of the arrow, so is not very useful for us to find out what is wrong in the navbar situation.